# How do I update a list of DOM objects relative to another set of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, dom

I’m curious from an academic perspective what kinds of loop algorythms are there to turn an array of objects into update instructions to another list of objects like you would in the DOM.

This is a computer science question that a *lot* of JavaScript frameworks attempt to solve. For example in React this is done by rendering a virtual DOM based on the new data and then comparing the old DOM to the new DOM. In Glimmer as the original DOM is created during the first run through the original array of objects it records the process and generates a set of virtual machine update instructions ready to be ran next time with a new set of input.

I’m interested in what this might look like from a pure non-framework perspective to help me learn loop-OOP-API algorithm(s).

Here is an example to help the question along. Start with a typical payload.

```
[
  {“id”: “foo1”, “name”: “Foo One”},
  {“id”: “foo2”, “name”: “Foo Two”},
  {“id”: “foo3”, “name”: “Foo Three”},
  {“id”: “foo4”, “name”: “Foo Four”},
  {“id”: “foo5”, “name”: “Foo Five”}
]
```

Which results in a list of DOM nodes each with a conceptual link to the original object (either by reference of by `id` value dependign on the implementation).

```
<p>ID foo1…</p>
<p>ID foo2…</p>
<p>ID foo3…</p>
<p>ID foo4…</p>
<p>ID foo5…</p>
```

Later the input changes

```
[
  {“id”: “foo3”, “name”: “Foo Three”},
  {“id”: “foo1”, “name”: “Foo One”},
]
```

Would result in `foo3` DOM node moving to the first location, `foo1` to the second, and the rest removed from the document. Assuming a large DOM is it important to not destroy the entire tree and rebuild new Nodes or re use ones that haven’t changed? How could an array loop correctly determine the moves and deletes?